# How would you setup a CSS3 fallback in IE for this slanted DIV navigation?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css

Taken from a tutorial at:  http://www.joecritchley.com/demos/slanted-nav/

I can't for the life of me get this to work in ANY version of IE.  It only displays the navigation as a normal bulleted list, but I know it must be possible based on some findings from http://css3please.com/ such as:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(20deg);  /* IE9 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */ 
M11=0.9396926207859084, M12=-0.3420201433256687, M21=0.3420201433256687, M22=0.9396926207859084, sizingMethod='auto expand');
           zoom: 1;
```

Here is the setup that is working in almost all other browsers:

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/zumajoe/9ukdm/

**CSS**

```
#main-nav > ul
{
margin-top:50px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#main-nav > ul > li
{
float:left;
font-size:18px;
margin-left:-35px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:20px;
}

#main-nav > ul > li:first-child
{
border-radius:10px;
margin-left:0;
}

#main-nav > ul > li > a
{
-moz-transform:rotate(20deg);
-o-transform:rotate(20deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);
background:#bbb;
border-left:1px solid #FFF;
color:#444;
display:block;
height:150px;
margin-bottom:-100px;
margin-top:-70px;
overflow:hidden;
text-decoration:none;
}

#main-nav > ul > li:first-child > a
{
border-left:0;
border-radius:10px;
}

#main-nav > ul > li > a > span
{
-moz-transform:rotate(-20deg);
-o-transform:rotate(-20deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg);
display:block;
margin-top:57px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0 20px;
}

#main-nav > ul > li > a:hover
{
background:#aaa;
}

#main-nav > ul > li.current > a
{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="main-nav"> 
            <ul> 
                <li class="current"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><span>News</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><span>Work</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><span>A longer menu item</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </nav>
```

EDIT:  Well half the problem comes from IE not understanding the HTML5 "Nav" tag, so changing the `<Nav>` to `<Div>` will at least get it to display as normal rectangles in IE.

EDIT #2:  The further I get along with this, i'm realizing it could just be easier to use the "skew" CSS3 property.   Skew the container, then skew back the span (same as how this rotation is setup).  Still have issues with IE 8,7, & 6 however.

Comment: Is JavaScript acceptable? It's truly hideous to do it without JavaScript, and requires a manual `width` set on each button.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use something like this: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/slanty.html - but that has problems with the slanted parts not always working properly.

Comment: I would rather not depend on JS for this, but if it's the only solution I don't have much of a choice!

Comment: I had actually seen that "slanty" menu before and forgot about it once I found that CSS3 tutorial by Joe Critchly as it seemed his solution was "cleaner".. but maybe I will go back to the other if I can't get this one going.

Comment: The [JavaScript library](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/) I was attempting to use to make this work in IE doesn't seem to work in this instance. Maybe somebody else has an alternative solution.

Comment: Hint: Rotating the `<span>` the opposite direction for IE is a bad solution, I just tried it [using this for help](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/) and it's very buggy and looks awful.

Comment: Wesley, do you know of any way around keeping the content within untouched so we don't have to rotate/skew back to original?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest simply using this: [CSS3 Transform to Matrix Filter Converter](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/index.html) and put the resulting code in an IE only stylesheet.

I've used it myself and found it works quite well.

As for the `<nav>` element, well you can use the [HTML5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) script to get HTML5 elements to work in IE.

Comment: Ian, my biggest issue with that converter is that it requires a width/height for the element.  I'm approaching a navigation setup that has width based on how much text is inside the button.  Any tips?

Comment: The width is only helps. I have created a navigation the same way you have, where the width is variable and it seems to work fine.

Comment: You got a live example?  I'm experiencing wackyness in IE6/7.  Are you using rotate or skew?

Comment: Skew. Hmm no, am afraid the site hasn't gone live yet.

Comment: Are your elemets able to be inline /flush with each other?  IE6/7 create a  "box" around the element, so it can never fully be flush with the element next to it.  (Creating a big gap)

Comment: Yes they are flush together. Am afraid I can't remember what I did, the code is at work and I'd have to look at it. Sorry :-/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `<nav>` element being unsupported in IE, which you already found out, I would say your best bet is conditional comments.  Thus:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
    #main-nav ul li a span{
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    #main-nav ul li {
        margin-left: -45px;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Adding that to the code you posted in your question makes it look acceptable, though clearly less sexy than the rotated version.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as simple as it seems. Basically, using CSS manipulators for this is tricky and always very limited.

However, there is a very alternative method called "[spiffy](http://www.spiffycorners.com/)". I personally don't use this and for such cases as in your question, I would simply use images. This was my official answer.

First spiffy slant menu script I came across was [Stu Nicholls "Slat Menu"](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/slanty.html). I styled it as in your example: **http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/LsVyY/** However, changing the angle of the corners is very very tricky and I basically gave up on that. If you understand the concept, and you choose to use this, then you can invest some time in it. Also, this seems not to work in IE8 (probably not in < IE's either.) So basically it fails.

---

Here are some links to some alternative slanted menus related articles:

- [The Impossible Slanted, Diagonal, Navigation Setup with CSS, jQuery & XHTML](http://www.kevinleary.net/the-impossible-slanted-diagonal-navigation-setup-with-css-jquery-xhtml/)
- [Slanted Divider Menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/slanted-divider-menu/)
- [cssSandpaper – a CSS3 JavaScript Library](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/)